# Is this lyric a metaphor?

Tags: metaphors, personification

From a Swedish song (translated):

> Standing at your door, just standing still
> A minute ago, you were mine
> **A third of who I was goes home**
> **Because one is crushed, one is yours**
> This is the end of our movie

Is that a metaphor? It's not literally meant, but it doesn't really compare two things either. If it's not, what is this called?

Obviously, he physically goes home (his whole body), but only a third of his soul/person accompanies his body, one third is crushed or ruined and the third part does still belong to and stays at his ex-girlfriend place.

**Edit:**
Would a personification be a better term to describe it? The soul is given human qualities- *goes* (or walks), is *crushed*, *belongs to*.

Also, it's more clear in Swedish that "who I was" refers to his soul and *not* his body. "A third of *the person I was* goes home" would perhaps be a better translation.

Comment: The comparison is between a fraction of the _body mass_ and an estimated equivalent proportion of one's ... I suppose, soul (I'll not define that more precisely). One could argue for a metaphor: the vehicle is the corporeal, the tenor the non-corporeal. But it _is_ unusual to have fanciful or at least non-corporeal tenor _and_ vehicle (what actually 'goes home'?)

Comment: A metaphor doesn't have to compare things. It just uses one thing to figuratively represent another thing.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly. What I understand this could mean is that his soul is crushed, his heart is his lover’s (apparently his ex-lover) and his corporeal body goes home.

Some people believe mankind to have three parts- body, heart and soul, so perhaps the author of those lines referred to that when he wrote these lines.

Comment: I didn't think of that, but yes, this is probably more accurate! Would this be some type of figure of speech or not?

Comment: Yes, I think it’s a metaphor. No one literally loses their heart to another or has their soul crushed, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a metaphor - at its basic level it is a mathematical model. The subject has divided his character into three parts, two of which have become unavailable: he feels the less for it.

If it helps, "*who I was*" can be substituted with "me" or "my personality" or "my emotions".